# Error Zoom (elevateZoom + cycle2) jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I was unable to run the jquery Cycle2 with elevateZoom but I apparently does not work starting in the second slider or transition.

Any chance to run when you click on next?

```
$(".zoom").elevateZoom({
    constrainType:"height",
    zoomType : "lens",
    cursor: "crosshair",
    containLensZoom: true,
    gallery:'cycle',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    galleryActiveClass: "cycle-slide-active"
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/csy2dh6b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code fix:

```
        $('#cycle').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function (event, optionHash) {
            var image = $("#cycle img.cycle-slide-active").attr('src');
            $(".zoomLens").css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
            return false;
        });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/csy2dh6b/2/